# SegFault deleting QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, unique-ptr, qtreewidgetitem

I am facing a strange problem in my code trying to deleting a `QTreeWidgetItem`. In particular, I have this in my class:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<QTreeWidgetItem>> mymap;
```

When I close my application, I have a SegFault, inside the default destructor of the `unique_ptr`. Then, I try to decompose the problem, and I create a destructor that does the following:

```
~MyClass() {
    for ( auto x = mymap.begin(); x != mymap.end(); x++  ) {
        QTreeWidgetItem* temp = x->second.release();
        qDebug() << "make sure the pointer is not broken " << temp->isDisabled();
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

The call to the function `isDisabled()` is useless, just to make sure that the pointer is not broken. Well, then I can use the object in the pointer, but when I try to delete it, I have the SegFault.

Any suggestion? Thanks to everybody

Comment: Why would you need to store `QTreeWidgetItems` as `unique_ptrs` in the first place? `QTreeWidgetItem` is designed to have `QTreeWidget` as its parent and hence this parent widget would be responsible for deleting the items when appropriate. What most likely happens in your case is double free because of two owners of the tree widget items: `QTreeWidget` and `unique_ptr`. Make sure you understand Qt's [parent-child relationships and memory management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, thanks for the comment. Well I understand this usage can be wird, but it should work. In the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html), QTreeWidgetItem is not a `QObject`. And anyway, in your link, it is written "When QObjects are created on the heap (i.e., created with new), a tree can be constructed from them in any order, and later, the objects in the tree can be destroyed in any order.", and I use `new` to create it. Last, in that case, I expect a SegFault when Qt try to delete the parent, but not in my line `delete temp`. Am I doing some mistake?

Comment: True, `QTreeWidgetItem` is not `QObject` although the similar principle applies to `QTreeWidget` and `QTreeWidgetItem`. The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dtor.QTreeWidget) on `QTreeWidget`'s destructor says it "destroys the tree widget and all its items". Why the segfault occurs on `delete temp` is hard to say. Check if `QTreeWidget` is still alive by that moment. If not, you're doing the second delete on the same pointer, hence the crash. Calling `temp->isDisabled()` checks nothing: if it's already deleted, it's just undefined behaviour - it may crash or it may not.

Comment: Good point. `QTreeWidget` was already deleted --.-- The undefined behaviour of `temp->isDisabled()` made me follow the wrong way... If you write it as an answer, I will accept it ;) thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTreeWidgetItems` are designed to be owned by `QTreeWidget`. As the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dtor.QTreeWidget) says, in the destructor of `QTreeWidget` all of its items are deleted. Having a `std::unique_ptr` to `QTreeWidgetItem` existing within `QTreeWidget` created the second independent ownership of `QTreeWidgetItem` and hence leads to double deletion of the same pointer. In your example the crash happens because by the moment of manual deletion the pointer has already been deleted along with `QTreeWidget` holding it.

Calling `temp->isDisabled()` does not really check for the pointer's validity: if the pointer has already been deleted, such a call just yields undefined behaviour - the app may crash or it may not.